# Ошибка при импорте - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу бота телеграм и получаю ошибку:

```
D:\python.exe D:/bott/bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/bott/bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    import telebot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Но модуль есть:

```
certifi 2019.9.11   2019.9.11
cffi    1.13.2  1.13.2
chardet 3.0.4   3.0.4
cryptography    2.8 2.8
future  0.18.2  0.18.2
idna    2.8 2.8
pip 19.3.1  19.3.1
pyTelegramBotAPI    3.6.6   3.6.6
pycparser   2.19    2.19
python-telegram-bot 12.2.0  12.2.0
requests    2.7.0   2.22.0
setuptools  41.2.0  41.6.0
six 1.13.0  1.13.0
telebot 0.0.3   0.0.3
tornado 6.0.3   6.0.3
urllib3 1.25.6  1.25.6
```

Comment: `No module named 'telebot'` — "Нет модуля с именем telebot". Вы уверены, что правильно его установили, введя команду `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`? Если ошиблись, то удалите его (`pip uninstall telebot`) и поставьте правильно.

Comment: переустановил но все так же

Comment: Может, Вы устанавливаете пакет в другую версию `Python`? В зависимости от неё, Вам могут помочь следующие команды: `pip3 install ...`, `python3 -m pip install ...`, `python3.x -m pip install ...` и т. д. Вам стоит выяснить, какой интерпретатор исполняет код, а какой связан с командой `pip`.

Comment: у меня версия python 3.8 а пишу на pycharm

Comment: Тогда в настройках Вы можете уточнить путь, по которому находится интерпретатор проекта. Может, это вообще виртуальное окружение?

Comment: путь python 3.8 D:/python.exe

Comment: Тогда попробуйте команду `python -m pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`.

Comment: не работает.....

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=3SvmrzqVmXo&si=EnSIkaIECMiOmarE вот в этом все очень доступно объяснили

Answer (score 4):

1. `pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`
2. `pip list` - проверить, установился ли pyTelegramBotAPI. Если в списке установленных модулей есть `telebot` - удалить. Должен остаться только `pyTelegramBotAPI`
3. При создании проекта в PyCharm указать путь до установленного интерпретатора python

[image: pycharm]

4. Пробовать запустить скрипт прямо в PyCharm. После этого пробовать запускать через командную строку(если необходимо).

Answer (score 0):

Набери ctr+alt+s там в поиске вбей Phython Interpreter, далее знак + и в поиске вставляешь pyTelegramBotAPI и нажимаешь Install Package.