# Причины возникновения ошибки ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'. Библиотека: pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем может быть связана данная ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "B:\shaihelper\telegabot.py", line 1, in 
> import telebot
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'

Код программы:

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('API-токен')

@bot.message_handler(command = ['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пока')

bot.polling()
```

Библиотека **`pyTelegramBotAPI`** установлена через **`cmd`**.

Библиотеки **`telebot`** нет.

Работаю через **`Sublime Text`**.

На компьютере установлены *Python 3.8* и *3.10*.

Comment: Возможно, вы используете виртуальную среду, т. е. в вашей папке создано локальное окружение python, но модуль вместо этого установлен глобально

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при импорте - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telebot'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043896/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-telebot)